# Loading Json File with Button Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a customization system that allows a player to customize their skin color and particle trail of their character. I have the system working and am now attempting to save the data through JsonUtility and then load it. I plan on saving the data with the play button then transitioning to a new scene and having it load at start() of the new scene. But, for testing I have been using a load button as it should still work...but it doesn't.

My current SaveSystem script is supposedly working since the DebugLog "Save file created" for saving files appears when the button is pressed. But, when pressing the load button nothing changes yet the DebugLog "Save file found and loaded" still appears. I am kinda lost as to where to go and how to load the data into the Customization script since I am still new to C# Json and serializing in general.

Here are my 3 scripts:

SaveSystem Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public static class SaveSystem
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public static class SaveSystem
{
public static string directory = "/saveData";
public static string fileName = "MyData.txt";

public static void SavePlayer(Customization CurrentCustomization)
{
    string dir = Application.persistentDataPath + directory;

    if(!Directory.Exists(dir))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        Debug.Log("Save file created");

    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(CurrentCustomization);
    File.WriteAllText(dir + fileName, json);
}

public static Customization LoadPlayer()
{
    string fullPath = Application.persistentDataPath + directory + fileName;
    Customization CurrentCustomization = new Customization();

    if(File.Exists(fullPath))
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
        CurrentCustomization = JsonUtility.FromJson<Customization>(json);

        Debug.Log("Save file found and loaded");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Save file does not exist");
    }

    return CurrentCustomization;
}
}
```

CharacterCustomizaiton Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class CharacterCustomization : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<Customization> Customizations;
public int currentCustomizationIndex;
public Customization CurrentCustomization {get; private set;}

[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI bodyColorText;
[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI trailText;

public void Save()
{
    SaveSystem.SavePlayer(CurrentCustomization);
}

public void Load()
{
    CurrentCustomization = SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();
}

void Awake()
{
    foreach(var customization in Customizations)
    {
        customization.UpdateSubObjects();
        customization.UpdateRenderers();
    }
}

public void SelectBodyColor(bool isForward)
{
    currentCustomizationIndex = 0;
    CurrentCustomization = Customizations[currentCustomizationIndex];
    if(isForward)
    {
        CurrentCustomization.NextMaterial();
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentCustomization.PreviousMaterial();
    }

    bodyColorText.text = CurrentCustomization.materialIndex.ToString();
}

public void SelectLTrail(bool isForward)
{
    currentCustomizationIndex = 1;
    CurrentCustomization = Customizations[currentCustomizationIndex];
    if(isForward)
    {
        CurrentCustomization.NextSubObject();
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentCustomization.PreviousSubObject();
    }        

    trailText.text = CurrentCustomization.subObjectIndex.ToString();
}

public void SelectRTrail(bool isForward)
{
    currentCustomizationIndex = 2;
    CurrentCustomization = Customizations[currentCustomizationIndex];
    if(isForward)
    {
        CurrentCustomization.NextSubObject();
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentCustomization.PreviousSubObject();
    }        

    trailText.text = CurrentCustomization.subObjectIndex.ToString();
}
}
```

Customization Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Customization
{
public string DisplayName;

public List<Renderer> Renderers;
public List<Material> Materials;
public List<GameObject> SubObjects;
public int materialIndex;
public int subObjectIndex;

public void NextMaterial()
{
    if(materialIndex == Materials.Count - 1)
    {
        materialIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        materialIndex++;
    }

    UpdateRenderers();
}

public void PreviousMaterial()
{
    if(materialIndex == 0)
    {
        materialIndex = Materials.Count - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        materialIndex--;
    }
    
    UpdateRenderers();
}

public void NextSubObject()
{
    if(subObjectIndex == SubObjects.Count - 1)
    {
        subObjectIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        subObjectIndex++;
    }

    UpdateSubObjects();
}

public void PreviousSubObject()
{
    if(subObjectIndex == 0)
    {
        subObjectIndex = SubObjects.Count - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        subObjectIndex--;
    }

    UpdateSubObjects();
}

public void UpdateSubObjects()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < SubObjects.Count; i++)
        if (SubObjects[i])
            SubObjects[i].SetActive(i == subObjectIndex);
}

public void UpdateRenderers()
{
    foreach (var renderer in Renderers)
        if (renderer)
            renderer.material = Materials[materialIndex];
}
}
```

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/save-monobehaviour-jsonutility.397595/

Comment: @shingo I read the article but am still quiete confused. I also realized that when saving my save system only saves the CurrentCustomization which is only 1 of 3 customizations. What I now realize is I need to save the List<Customizations> Customizations; but do not know how to since <Customization> does not convert to Customization class

Comment: That's not the major problem. Unity objects (GameObject, Renderer, etc..) are serialized with their instanceIDs (what is metioned in the article). And you can also take a look at the saved file. That means the properties of these objects are not saved. Further read: https://forum.unity.com/threads/arent-gameobjects-suppose-to-be-serializable.488577/

Comment: @shingo okay how would I go upon looping through each list within the Customizations list and defining them? Sorry I am just a bit confused as I am new to Json serializing and deserializing. Thank you for your help!

Comment: here's my inspector if it helps to visualize what I am after saving. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ybX3dCMU5uJs0HOiTPpRnOpmTgzQIsos/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `JsonUtility.ToJson(Customizations)`